# Advanced photo uploader plugin - any suggestions for one that can do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, upload, photo

I have an app where I want users to be able to upload a photo for their profile. The photo will be quite big on their profile page - 640x360px which translates to 16:9 ratio which seems to be the standard image size from a digital camera.

I haven't done this before (bit of a noob) and there's a couple of things I don't know whats the best way to handle.

So I want an 'upload image' button which causes a popup which allows the user to resize or crop the image they're uploading so if fits nicely into a 640x360px div. But if the image they're uploading is, for example, 16:16 ratio and 5000px wide, then obviously it needs to be resized before being shown to the user where he can then crop the image to fit into my required 16:9 ratio.

Equally if the image the user wants to use it tiny I want to encourage them to scale their picture up so if fits nicely into the div I want it in.

I guess this is a common problem and I'm hoping there's a plugin but after sifting for an hour or so through the endless plugins on jQuery's plugin website I couldn't spot one which actually does the above.

I'm looking for some recommendations from some smart people :)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really a common problem, and file upload is actually fairly difficult. The problem is that you are very restricted because of security concerns.

What you could do is just do a normal file upload (there are plenty of tutorials online if you need help with that), and then use ImageMagick to resize the images to the resolution you want serverside.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've looked at imagemagick and it seems similar to other plugins I've seen. Is this just the usual way of handling it. We have to do the image manipulation ourselves? I could have sworn I saw something that allowed users to crop images. What are the security problems? thanks

Comment: Sure, there are websites that allow you to crop your images (Facebook i believe), however those are fairly complicated, and usually dependant on the server they are hosted on. You'd have to write your own solution here.

Comment: File upload is very limited, you cant have access to the user's harddrive for obvious security concerns. For example, its also not possible to easily style a file input element.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd need access to the users harddrive. Surely you could upload a photo to your own server then display it to them allowing them to crop or resize, then save the new file and delete the old file? Is it not possible to do something like that? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes its possible, but there arent any readily available plugins for it i bet. You'd have to make your own, and come up with more specific questions if you run into trouble.